# How do I solve this p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m using Dynamic Programming Top Down approach?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem from Codeforces (http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/189/A)
Here's the problem statement:

> Polycarpus has a ribbon, its length is n. He wants to cut the ribbon in a way that fulfils the following two conditions:
>
> After the cutting each ribbon piece should have length a, b or c.
>   After the cutting the number of ribbon pieces should be maximum.
>   Help Polycarpus and find the number of ribbon pieces after the required 
>   cutting.
>
> Input
>   The first line contains four space-separated integers n, a, b and c (1 ≤ n, a, b, c ≤ 4000) — the length of the original ribbon and the acceptable lengths of the ribbon pieces after the cutting, correspondingly. The numbers a, b and c can coincide.
>
> Output
>   Print a single number — the maximum possible number of ribbon pieces. It is guaranteed that at least one correct ribbon cutting exists.
>
> Sample Input
>
> 5 5 3 2
>
> Sample Output
>
> 2

I tried to solve this problem using Dynamic Programming (Topdown approach). But I'm not able to get the correct answer. There might be something wrong with the recursive function. Here's my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n,s;
int a[3];
int val,m=-1;
int dp(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(n>=a[i])
        {
            val=1+dp(n-a[i]);
        }
    }
    if(val>m)
        m=val;
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&n,&a[0],&a[1],&a[2]);
    cout<<dp(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem in the above approach?

Comment: To start with, you shouldn't usually include the `<bits/*>` header files, and especially not `<bits/stdc++.h` unless you really need all the headers that file includes. Include *only* the header files you need, which in your case would be `<cstdio>` and `<iostream>`. And is there a reason you use `scanf` in a C++ program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know that it's not a good way to use <bits/stdc++.h> or scanf in C++ code. But these tactics are used in programming contests. This is my code for  programming contest problem.

Comment: Just because other people are having bad habits, doesn't mean you should have it. If you want to become a good programmer, use good programming techniques and good habits from the start. And don't do programming contests, they won't really make you into a good programmer, unless you consider obfuscated and uncommented code good. Learn good programming techniques, basic and advanced data structures and algorithms, and most of all how to write good, readable and maintainable code, *then* start working on those contests if you still want to.

Comment: I don't think you should use dp here, for something like 10000 1 2 3 your approach will probably take hours to compute.

Comment: If you break it down for the input of "5 5 3 2", you at some point get the val = 1, after you've done n = 5, n = 0 ( 1 + dp(0) ), val = 1. Then when you do 5 - 2 - 2 you have 1 left and then all of your tests if(n >= a[i]) fail and you return val, which is 1, then you add that 1 to 1, when you have 5 - 2 - 2 and you do val = 1 + dp(1), so far you have 2, then you add that 2 to another 1, when you do val = 1 + dp(3), so altogether you get 3. For the input of "7 5 5 2" you subtract 2 from 7 3 times and you're left with 1 in the end and it still counts it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems:

**Wrong Search**

In your lines

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if(n>=a[i])
    {
        val=1+dp(n-a[i]);
    }
}
if(val>m)
    m=val;
```

You should be checking for the maximum of the different `val`s obtained for the different choices of `i`.

**Wrong Termination**

If the length is not 0 and no ribbon can be cut, you should return something like minus infinity. You currently return `m` which is initially -1 (more on this later). This is wrong, and for long ribbons will essentially ensure that you just choose the minimum of a, b, and c.

**Use of Globals**

Some globals, e.g., `m` are initialized once but are modified by the recursion. It's not "just" bad programming habits - it's not doing what you want.

**No Reuse**

By calling the recursion unconditionally, and not reusing previous calls, your running time is needlessly high.

Comment: I used (n>=a[i]) to prevent from having negative parameter for the function dp. Because dp(some negative number) is of no use. This is my assumption. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @ScottWu it's true that by the statement of the problem cut always exists, however you still have 1st and 3rd problems from the list, and also time limit probably

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
 int n, a, b, c;
 scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &cuts[0], &cuts[1], &cuts[2]);
 sort(cuts, cuts + 3);
 for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    max_cuts[i] = INT_MIN;
 }

 max_cuts[0] = 0;
 max_cuts[cuts[0]] = 1;
 max_cuts[cuts[1]] = 1;
 max_cuts[cuts[2]] = 1;

 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (cuts[j] > i) break;
        max_cuts[i] = max(max_cuts[i - cuts[j]] + 1, max_cuts[i]);
    }
 }
 printf("%d\n", max_cuts[n]);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ami Tavory correctly suggested the problems with your recursive approach. May be my solution below can help you understand better how to form states and check bounds:

```
    int main()
    {
            int n, a, b, c;
            cin >> n >> a >> b >> c; 

            const int l = n + 1;
            int sum[l];
            fill(sum, sum+l, INT_MIN);
            sum[0] = 0;

            for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                    if(i - a >= 0)
                    {
                            sum[i] = sum[i-a] + 1;
                    }
                    if(i - b >= 0 && sum[i-b] + 1 > sum[i])
                    {
                            sum[i] = sum[i-b] + 1;
                    }
                    if(i - c >= 0 && sum[i-c] + 1 > sum[i])
                    {
                            sum[i] = sum[i-c] + 1;
                    }

            }
            cout << sum[n] << endl;
            return 0;
    }
```

Simply at each sum[i], we are maximizing the number of cuts. So, at sum[i], we are storing the max(sum[i-a]+1, sum[i-b]+1, sum[i-c]+1). 
Other than this, there are just bound checks.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem through top down approach.A dp problem always check all the possible cases then gives us the optimal solution.so here is the code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int a,b,c;
int DP[4001];
int solve(int n){
if(n == 0)return 0;
if(n<0) return INT_MIN;
if(DP[n] != -1)return DP[n];
else{
   DP[n] = max(1+solve(n-a),max(1+solve(n-b),1+solve(n-c)));
return DP[n];
}
}
int main(){
int n,x;
cin>>n>>a>>b>>c;
for(int i = 0;i<4001;++i){
DP[i] = -1;
}
x = solve(n);
cout<<x;
}
```